# Two Operating Systems in a single Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Is it possible to run two different operating systems in a single Vagrantfile? When I have the following Vagrantfile it creates both as debain10, where I really wanted one centos8 *and* one debian10. This is the (failing) Vagrantfile I'm using:

```
#-*-mode:ruby-*-
#vi:setft=ruby:

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION="2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # Configure the CentOS Machines.
  config.vm.box = "generic/centos8"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.memory = 512
    v.linked_clone = true
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nested-hw-virt", "on"]
  end

  # Ideally this should be a centos8 machine
  config.vm.define "centos8-server" do |config|
    config.vm.hostname = "centos8-server"
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.20.100"
  end

  # Ideally this should be a debian10 machine
  config.vm.box = "generic/debian10"
  config.vm.define "debian10-server" do |config|
    config.vm.hostname = "debian10-server"
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.20.200"
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub").first.strip
    s.inline = <<-SHELL
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
      echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> ~vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
    SHELL
  end

end
```

The reason I want to do this is that I have a need to test a single ansible playbook against a set of CentOS and Debian machine. I'm not sure if this is possible as its not explicitly shown as unsupported in the documentation. Prior to this I've been running two Vagrantfile's but I'm keen to see if it can be achieved in a single file.

Answer (score 3):

Relocate the source box definition to under the undividual machine block.  See here by example (it's easier just to show it) - I have written a simpler one you may want to modify if you desire:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # box 1 - centos
  config.vm.define "centos" do |centos|
    centos.vm.box = "centos/7"
    centos.vm.hostname = "centos"
    centos.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.75.10"
    # setting name of vm to inspect in virtualbox
    centos.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.name = "centos"
    end
  # box 2 - ubuntu
  end
  config.vm.define "ubuntu" do |ubuntu|
    ubuntu.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    ubuntu.vm.hostname = "ubuntu"
    ubuntu.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.75.11"
    # setting name of vm to inspect in virtualbox
    ubuntu.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.name = "ubuntu"
    end
  end
end
```